# How can an indexed property return a reference?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following code fails to compile using Visual Studio 2012 with error: *C2234: 'Foo' : arrays of references are illegal*

```
struct MyClass
{
  int m_var;
  __declspec(property(get=GetFoo)) int& Foo[];   // < C2234
  int& GetFoo(int) { return m_var; }
};
```

I wonder why this is the case.

Yes, arrays of references are forbidden by the standard.
However, Foo[] is not an array but sort of a symbolic link to the member function GetFoo().
It behaves just as if Foo was a class with an overloaded indexing operator.
On the other side, the following code is perfectly legal, although it is technically equivalent to the previous snippet:

```
struct FooClass
{
    int m_var;
    int& operator[](int) { return m_var; }
};

struct MyClass
{
    FooClass Foo;
};
```

So why is error C2234 issued? Is this a compiler design bug?

BTW.: The real scenario is more complex, so there is no need to tell me that handing over references to members may be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

I am not surprised by this error because `int& Foo[];` is the declaration of an array of int references. The grammar for `__declspec(property)` specifies that what follows this keyword is a declarator: [__declspec(property) documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Therefore, you should treat the text at the right of your `__declspec(property)` as a declaration and not as some supposedly special symbolic link.

As you and your compiler have pointed out, declaring arrays of references is forbidden. `__declspec(property)` makes no exception to that rule.

You can use this alternative:

```
struct MyClass
{
    int m_var;
    __declspec(property(get=GetFoo,put=SetFoo)) int Foo[];   // < C2234
    int& GetFoo(int) { return m_var; }
    void SetFoo(int, int v) {m_var = v;}
};

int main()
{ 
    MyClass test;
    test.Foo[0] = 5;

    std::cout << test.Foo[0];

    return 0;
}
```

If I were you I would stick to the good ol' operator[] which is standard C++. `__declspec` syntax is specific to Microsoft's Visual Studio.